# Where is std::cin when std::cout is going to the "Output" pane of VSCode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, std, vscode-code-runner

When I do a "Run Code" command in Visual Studio Code in Windows (it's the first option when I right-click in the editor), the `std::cout` output goes to the "Output" pane of VSCode. But when this happens, where is `std::cin`? You can't type in the "Output" pane, and the code hangs at any `cin` lines.

Is there some other place that's working as `std::cin` when I run this way? And if not, is there some way to configure the "Run Code" command so that `cin` and `cout` go to a terminal? I've already tried editing the `console` argument of settings.json, like the first solution to [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/449) github issue (or its latest equivalent, since the `externalConsole` option is deprecated), but it doesn't help, I think because output just isn't going to any console at all.

(also, the "Run Code" command does not enter a debugging session, just compiles and executes. Regular debugging works fine and `cin` and `cout` go to the terminal specified in settings.json)

Comment: If you're [debugging](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging), you should see output in debug console.

Comment: Sorry, the debug and run I mean (whatever F5 does by default). In any case, ```cin``` isn't broken during debugging and that's not what I'm asking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you say is provided with two extension of VSCode.

- The "Run Code" command in right click menu is likely provided by extension [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner)
- The 'settings.json' and the [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/449) talks about the Microsoft's official C/C++ support extension [C/C++](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools)

For you case, you may need to set this setting for `Code Runner` if you want to use the stdin of process

```json
"code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
```